# Is there a more efficient way to reverse the rows of a ragged 2D array in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I wrote a method that flips the rows of a ragged java array, however this involves 4 different for loops, with two of them being nested loops. Is there a better, more efficient way to tackle this?

I tried to find the row sizes of the flipped array by looping through and initializing an array that stores the flipped row sizes.
I then initialized a newData array with these new row sizes.
Next I loaded the newData array with the values from the original data array, in reverse row order.
I then re-initialized the data array so that i can copy the newData array back into the original data array.

```
public static void flipMatRows(int[][] data) {
    int[] rowSizes = new int[data.length];
    // find row sizes of newData array
    int[][] newData = new int[rowSizes.length][];
    int i = 0;
    for (int row = data.length - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        rowSizes[i] = data[row].length;
        i++;
    }
    // initialize empty ragged array based off row sizes
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        newData[row] = new int[rowSizes[row]];
    }
    // load newData with values
    int reverseRow = data.length - 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < newData.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < newData[row].length; col++) {
            newData[row][col] = data[reverseRow][col];
        }
        reverseRow--;
    }
    // re-initialize data array based off flipped row sizes
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        data[row] = new int[rowSizes[row]];
    }
    // load newData back into original data array
    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
            data[row][col] = newData[row][col];
        }
    }
    printMat(data);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't look like it is "reversing the rows...", it looks like it is "creating a copy of the array with a copy of the rows, in reverse order".  Do you really need that?  (And also, you have 5 loops, not 4 as stated in the question)

Comment: Off-topic: You're welcome.  For future reference, if you ever need to actually copy an array, or part of an array,  the [`Arrays` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has several `static` methods for doing that, as well as  other methods for operating on arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static void flipRows (int [][] arr) {
    int [] temp;
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
       temp = arr [i];
       arr[i] = arr [j];
       arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

In Java, an array is *reference*, i.e., an [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). And, Java doesn't have true 2D arrays: It has only 1D arrays. But, an  array can be an array of references. So, a declaration such as
`int [][] matrix;`  specifies `matrix` is an array of references, and each of those references is an array of `int`.  One consequence is that "ragged 2D" arrays are allowed. Another consequence is swapping rows of a 2D array is as easy as swapping elements of a 1D array of `Object`. Reversing rows of a 2D array is as easy as reversing elements in a 1D array of `Object`.

Test driver and print:

```
public static void printMat (int [][] arr) {
    for (int [] row : arr) {
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
    
public static void testRowFlip () {
    int  [][] testArr = {{0,1,2,3},{4},{-4},{5,6,7,8,9,10},{},{11,12}};
    flipRows (testArr);
    printMat (testArr);
    System.out.println ("end of flip rows");
}
```

Example output:

```
[11, 12]
[]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[-4]
[4]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
end of flip rows
```

Comment: Your snippet works but is convoluted. There's a much, _much_ simpler way: `Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arr))`. - that's it. I notice that virtually all usages of `asList` are abuse - and should have been `List.of`. The __actual__ purpose of `Arrays.asList` (exactly this), that's something I rarely witness. (Note: This modifies the actual array. asList creates a wrapper, not a clone).

Comment: I am aware of the `Collections.Reverse` method. However, I thought the O/P would benefit from seeing an approach that *explicitly* used each row of an 2D array as an Object.